# Getting PatientType is not defined while conditional rendering in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am trying to render columns in a table based on a condition.

```
 { 
        dataField: PatientType=="Self" ? "PatientData.name" : "name",  
        text: "Name",
        sort: true,
      },
```

This is the code that I have written, I want to get dataField:PatientData.name if condition is true otherwise I want dataField:name

However if I write code this way it says PatientType is undefined.

If I write dataField:PatientType it renders that field correctly however in conditional statement I get "PatientType" is undefined.

I have also tried writing it as

```
this.props.pendingappointments.PatientType=="Self"
```

and it still returns undefined.

pendingappointments is where I am getting data from redux state
and PatientType is a field inside the pendingappointments object

This is the full code for table:

```
class PendingAptList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      deleteModal: false,
      modal: false,
      subscribemodal: false,
        pendingappointments: this.props,
      AppointmentListColumns: [
        {
          dataField: "id", 
          text: "Appointment ID", 
          sort: true, 
          hidden: true,
          formatter: (
            
            cellContent, 
            row //row= object
          ) => (
            <Link to="#" className="text-body fw-bold">
              {row.id}
            </Link>
          ),
        },
     
        { 
        
            dataField: "PatientData.name",
            text: "Name",
            sort: true,
          },
        
        {
          dataField: "ReqDate",
          text: "Request Date",
          sort: true,
        },
       
        {
            dataField: "ReqTime",
            text: "Request Time",
            sort: true,
          },
          {
            dataField: "Status",
            text: "Status",
            sort: true,
            formatter: (cellContent, row) => (
              <Badge 
              bg="danger"
              className={"font-size-12 badge-soft-" + row.badgeclass}  
            //   color={row.badgeclass}   
              >
                {row.Status}
              </Badge>
            ),
          },
          {
            dataField: "Price",
            text: "Price",
            sort: true,
          },
```

This is the pendingapppointments Object

```
    {
  payload: [
    {
      id: '57d087b9-0725-4458-9301-e8bf9b53c877',
      PatientData: {
        Gender: 'Male',
        address: null,
        email: 'test@digilab.com',
        name: 'Test Subject',
        contact_number: '123123232',
        is_patient: true,
        is_doctor: false,
        is_homesampler: false,
        is_pathologist: false,
        is_admin: false,
        is_staff: false,
        is_active: true,
        is_lab: false,
        date_joined: '2022-08-21T09:34:10.991286Z',
        last_login: '2022-08-21T09:34:10.991286Z'
      },
      Status: 'Pending Response',
      Price: '3300.00',
      PaymentType: null,
      ReqDate: '2022-08-30',
      ReqTime: '20:54:40.404144',
      Address: null,
      longitude: null,
      latitude: null,
      PatientType: 'Self',
      name: null,
      age: null,
      contact: null,
      Gender: null,
      Notes: '',
      Patient_id: 'test@digilab.com',
      Lab_Id: 'Shifa@mail.com',
      BookedServices: [
        {
          id: '0db917ee-ffb7-461c-bbdf-f7481e728a7e',
          ServiceData: {
            id: 'bbbf6818-b88a-4e94-9d5c-7a02638961e6',
            TestData: {
              id: 'c7daf9e5-71ec-4f98-8b6f-32f61e2cdf67',
              Title: 'Random Test',
              Description: 'xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD ',
              PreConditions: 'don\'t eat anything for 2 hrs prior',
              LowerPriceLimit: 1000,
              UpperPriceLimit: 2000,
              AvgDuration: '2hrs'
            },
            LabData: {
              address: 'N/A',
              longitude: 112.22,
              latitude: 2.22,
              landline_number: '83848348843',
              health_department_id: '5755775',
              Logo: null,
              verified: false,
              email: 'Shifa@mail.com',
              name: 'shiffaa',
              contact_number: '83848348843',
              is_patient: false,
              is_doctor: false,
              is_homesampler: false,
              is_pathologist: false,
              is_admin: false,
              is_staff: false,
              is_active: true,
              is_lab: true,
              date_joined: '2022-08-11T09:49:02.952460Z',
              last_login: '2022-08-11T09:49:02.952460Z'
            },
            ServiceTitle: 'Random Test',
            ServiceDescription: 'A complete blood count (CBC) is a blood test used to evaluate your overall health and detect a wide range of disorders, including anemia, infection and leukemia.A complete blood count test measures several components and features of your blood, including:',
            Duration: '29:19:02',
            HomeSampling: true,
            HomeSamplingPrice: 300,
            ServicePrice: 1500,
            Communication: true,
            CommunicationPrice: 1800,
            Test_id: 'c7daf9e5-71ec-4f98-8b6f-32f61e2cdf67',
            Lab_id: 'Shifa@mail.com'
          },
          Results: null,
          Result_Upload_Time: null,
          BookedServiceStatus: 'wating',
          HomeSampling: false,
          Communication: true,
          RequestedTime: '2022-09-01T20:48:00Z',
          Lab_note: null,
          Appointment_id: '57d087b9-0725-4458-9301-e8bf9b53c877',
          Service_id: 'bbbf6818-b88a-4e94-9d5c-7a02638961e6'
        },
        {
          id: '18e68387-0904-412e-8d31-96b548e4c950',
          ServiceData: {
            id: '14954cf7-62c7-4e9a-9bc4-5bcc73e48a9f',
            TestData: {
              id: 'c7daf9e5-71ec-4f98-8b6f-32f61e2cdf67',
              Title: 'Random Test',
              Description: 'xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD xD ',
              PreConditions: 'don\'t eat anything for 2 hrs prior',
              LowerPriceLimit: 1000,
              UpperPriceLimit: 2000,
              AvgDuration: '2hrs'
            },
            LabData: {
              address: 'Lahore',
              longitude: 112.22,
              latitude: 2.22,
              landline_number: '0312-1122334',
              health_department_id: '1122211',
              Logo: null,
              verified: true,
              email: 'Chughtai@mail.com',
              name: 'Chughtaiii',
              contact_number: '0312-112233456',
              is_patient: false,
              is_doctor: false,
              is_homesampler: false,
              is_pathologist: false,
              is_admin: false,
              is_staff: false,
              is_active: false,
              is_lab: true,
              date_joined: '2022-08-30T06:02:09.831414Z',
              last_login: '2022-08-30T06:02:09.831414Z'
            },
            ServiceTitle: 'Random Test',
            ServiceDescription: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentiumsapiente officiis modi at sunt excepturi expedita sint?',
            Duration: '29:19:02',
            HomeSampling: true,
            HomeSamplingPrice: 200,
            ServicePrice: 2000,
            Communication: true,
            CommunicationPrice: 1800,
            Test_id: 'c7daf9e5-71ec-4f98-8b6f-32f61e2cdf67',
            Lab_id: 'Chughtai@mail.com'
          },
          Results: null,
          Result_Upload_Time: null,
          BookedServiceStatus: 'wating',
          HomeSampling: false,
          Communication: false,
          RequestedTime: '2022-08-09T18:00:00Z',
          Lab_note: null,
          Appointment_id: '57d087b9-0725-4458-9301-e8bf9b53c877',
          Service_id: '14954cf7-62c7-4e9a-9bc4-5bcc73e48a9f'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: '97b6489b-0d40-4edd-8928-af673412bfce',
      PatientData: {
        Gender: 'Male',
        address: null,
        email: 'test@digilab.com',
        name: 'Test Subject',
        contact_number: '123123232',
        is_patient: true,
        is_doctor: false,
        is_homesampler: false,
        is_pathologist: false,
        is_admin: false,
        is_staff: false,
        is_active: true,
        is_lab: false,
        date_joined: '2022-08-21T09:34:10.991286Z',
        last_login: '2022-08-21T09:34:10.991286Z'
      },
      Status: 'Pending Response',
      Price: '2800.00',
      PaymentType: null,
      ReqDate: '2022-08-30',
      ReqTime: '21:03:39.751974',
      Address: null,
      longitude: null,
      latitude: null,
      PatientType: 'Other',
      name: 'Alishbah Sardar',
      age: 23,
      contact: '0336-0113984',
      Gender: 'Female',
      Notes: '',
      Patient_id: 'test@digilab.com',
      Lab_Id: 'Shifa@mail.com',
      BookedServices: [
        {
          id: 'c121b4c1-6049-4326-a603-3ef38e1f019a',
          ServiceData: {
            id: '9a6575cf-f577-462c-a1d0-30bbdf4a41f7',
            TestData: {
              id: '34dbb9c4-e844-41eb-befb-2af66c989876',
              Title: 'CBC',
              Description: 'enter something about test here which idk but I have to keep writing because the text limit is 100 sjadkjskd',
              PreConditions: 'Don\'t eat anything 2 hours prior',
              LowerPriceLimit: 150,
              UpperPriceLimit: 200,
              AvgDuration: '2 hr'
            },
            LabData: {
              address: 'N/A',
              longitude: 112.22,
              latitude: 2.22,
              landline_number: '83848348843',
              health_department_id: '5755775',
              Logo: null,
              verified: false,
              email: 'Shifa@mail.com',
              name: 'shiffaa',
              contact_number: '83848348843',
              is_patient: false,
              is_doctor: false,
              is_homesampler: false,
              is_pathologist: false,
              is_admin: false,
              is_staff: false,
              is_active: true,
              is_lab: true,
              date_joined: '2022-08-11T09:49:02.952460Z',
              last_login: '2022-08-11T09:49:02.952460Z'
            },
            ServiceTitle: 'CBC',
            ServiceDescription: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentiumsapiente officiis modi at sunt',
            Duration: '29:19:02',
            HomeSampling: false,
            HomeSamplingPrice: 0,
            ServicePrice: 2700,
            Communication: true,
            CommunicationPrice: 100,
            Test_id: '34dbb9c4-e844-41eb-befb-2af66c989876',
            Lab_id: 'Shifa@mail.com'
          },
          Results: null,
          Result_Upload_Time: null,
          BookedServiceStatus: 'wating',
          HomeSampling: false,
          Communication: true,
          RequestedTime: '2022-09-08T21:03:00Z',
          Lab_note: null,
          Appointment_id: '97b6489b-0d40-4edd-8928-af673412bfce',
          Service_id: '9a6575cf-f577-462c-a1d0-30bbdf4a41f7'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: where is the PatientType? i don't see it in code

Comment: its a field in the pendingappointments, getting it from backend

Comment: You need to share the code where you pass `PatientType` to `PendingAptList`.

Comment: I am getting it from pendingappointments=this,.props and I have shown the pendingappointments object now, it has a field PatientType which I am trying to pass